# Alternate definition of ordinals ?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Hello, recently I came upon some personal notes I'd made several years ago while reviewing some basic set theory (ordinals, transfinite recursion, inaccessible cardinals etc.), and I stumbled upon a loose thread which I obviously had not resolved at the time, and which I would like to lay to rest:
Assuming some standard set theory (say ZF, even though I prefer NBG), without the Axiom of Foundation (preferably), one may define an ordinal $\alpha$ (von Neumann's definition) as a transitive set whose elements are well-ordered with respect to the membership relation $\in$. This is seen to be equivalent to the statement that $\alpha$ is transitive, all its $\beta\in\alpha$ are transitive too, and (as we cannot rely on foundation) for each non-empty $x\subseteq\alpha$ there exists some $\beta\in x$ such that $x\cap\beta=\emptyset$ (except for the last condition, this is as in Schofield's book on Mathematical Logic). One then goes on to prove that the class of all ordinals is well-ordered with respect to membership etc.; along the way a useful intermediate step is to prove that any ordinal $\alpha$ is (ad hoc definition) $\textbf{strange}$ in the sense that one has $x\in\alpha$ for any transitive $x\subsetneq\alpha$.
My question finally (as this would provide an alternate definition of ordinal sets): are elements of strange sets themselves strange, or at least transitive ?
Thanks in advance for any useful comments ! Kind regards, Stephan F. Kroneck.

Comment: @Soham Unlike other Stackexchange sites, salutations and signatures are fine here.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo ah, my apologies. Thank you for reverting the edit.

Comment: Also on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62716/alternate-definition-of-ordinal-sets

Answer (score 16):

**Theorem.** Every strange set is an ordinal.

Proof. Suppose that $\alpha$ is strange. Let $\beta$ be the smallest ordinal such that $\beta\notin\alpha$. Such a $\beta$ exists, because no set can contain all the ordinals, and this does not require the foundation axiom to prove. It follows that $\beta\subset\alpha$ and $\beta$ is transitive. Thus, if $\beta\neq\alpha$, we would have $\beta\in\alpha$, contradicting the choice of $\beta$. Hence $\beta=\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is an ordinal. QED

Comment: Update: I haven't given the whole matter terribly much thought recently, apart from the fact that I'm able to prove that strange sets are necessearily hereditarily transitive (what a mouthful !) and that no element of a strange set has itself as a member (directly using the definition, avoiding the whole ordinal machinery), and (what is then quite easy) that strange sets are ordered linearly w.r.t. subset inclusion. What remains is the original loose end: avoiding ordinals, just using the definition, why are elements of strnage sets again strange ? (ctd. below)

Comment: (ctd.)  Thus I wish to leave the question open (and prefer not to hand out an "answered" just yet). Kind regards to all who have contributed their time and insights so far ! S.F. Kroneck.

Answer (score 15):

Strange sets are the same thing as ordinals. Given a strange set $\alpha$, let $\beta$ be the smallest ordinal such that $\beta\notin\alpha$. Then $\beta\subseteq\alpha$. If $\beta\subsetneq\alpha$, then $\beta\in\alpha$ as $\alpha$ is strange, which contradicts the definition of $\beta$. Thus $\beta=\alpha$.

Comment: Emil, it looks like we hit on the same observation.

Comment: Indeed. And I find the observation somewhat interesting in that it provides a definition of ordinals in ZF which works in the absense of the foundation axiom, despite that it does not refer to well-foundedness (or well-order). (It does, however, quantify over subsets of $\alpha$, which is to be expected, as ordinals are not definable by a bounded formula in ZF minus foundation.)

Comment: Well, the way that well-foundedness works its way in is in the definition of ordinal. I have seen alternative definitions of ordinal in the anti-foundation context simply as "hereditarily transitive" sets, dropping the well-founded part of the definition. I'm not sure, but I think that some intuitionists use something like this also, and perhaps they (or you?) can tell us. 

Comment: $\textbf{Thank you}$ already for your comments; indeed, the reason for considering strange sets is precisely that one avoids the whole notion of well-order, and needs to verify membership of a set only one level (as say compared to the hereditarily transitive version); still, I was hoping for a more direct proof (from the definition) that elements of strange sets are again strange (and avoiding any already developed theory of ordinals in the usual sense) - I should have phrased my question more precisely. (ctd. below) 

Comment: @Joel: I think we are talking past each other. I’m not interested in a definition of alternative ordinals (such as hereditarily transitive sets, which do not have any useful properties without the foundation axiom), but alternative definitions of the standard class of ordinals. Its usual definitions explicitly involve the condition of well-foundedness in one way or another (such as by demanding that the set be well-ordered by ∈), which is rather inelegant. In contrast the definition of a strange set does not invoke well-foundedness in any way, it only refers to its transitive subsets. ...

Comment: ... As for intuitionistic set theories: the usual ones (IZF, CZF) include the foundation axiom (in the form of $\in$-induction).

Comment: (ctd.) Another remark: the quantization over subsets does not seem (to me) to be such a drawback (subsets are, of course, simply sets whose elements also lie in the putative superset). In fact, an advantage of the definition is that it can be reformulated for classes (consider all $\textbf{subclasses}$ $x\subsetneq\alpha$), and yields the class of all strange/ordinal sets as the unique proper strange class. Naturally, this class formation is not $\textit{per se}$ predicative (and thus not permissible in NBG, though it is in MK), but can be made so due to the Axiom of Separation. (ctd. below)

Comment: (ctd.) Interestingly, due to Separation, a large corpus of the elementary theory of ordinals remains provable. In fact, my motivation for the whole business was to give a slick exposition of the equivalence of the (strong version) of the Axiom of Limitation of Size (in NBG, be it in injective or surjective form)) with the combined Axioms of Global Choice and Replacement, $\textbf{without}$ use of the Axiom of Power Sets (because Limitation yields this inthe special instances required), and implying (as observed by Azriel Lévy, the Axiom of Union.

Comment: slight (copy + paste) typo: (strong version) of Global Choice, not Limitation, naturally ! 

Comment: A contrary point is that saying "$\alpha$ is well-ordered by $\in$'' is about the same complexity as "$\alpha$ is strange", and quantifies over the same collection of subsets of $\alpha$, so it isn't clear if one is really saving any set-theoretical baggage this way.